# Updating Facebook Page From Twitter

Tags: facebook, twitter

I'm looking for a service (or Facebook app) that will check my Twitter account and update my Facebook page whenever there is a new post on Twitter. So far I've tried the following to no avail:

- Twitter facebook app
- Ping.fm
- HelloTxt.com

Any ideas what I can use to do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I use Selective Twitter Status, it's a Facebook app (3rd party) that reads your Twitter stream and updates your Facebook status from it. The advantage of this app is that it's selective, it only updates FB if your tweet ends in '#fb'.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Facebook profile, right below your status, click Options and then Settings.

You should be able to select Blog/RSS under the Imported Stories and then put in the link to your twitter's RSS feed.